# Regex - characters after delimiter, limited to a number

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to put together some regex to get *only* the first 16 characters *after* the `:`

```
blahblahblah:fakeblahfakeblahfakeblahfakeblah
```

I came up with
`/[^:]*$`
but that matches everything after the colon and if I try to trim from there its actually starting at the last character.

Comment: You could use a capture group if after the first colon `^[^:]*:([^:]{16})` https://regex101.com/r/xpL2DY/1 or after the last colon `^.*:([^:]{16})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
(?<=:)[^:]{16}(?=[^:]*$)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/gYahXs/2)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^:]{16}                 any character except: ':' (16 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]*                    any character except: ':' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: This worked perfect and thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Its not often I come away from a question having learned as much

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a capturing group, first matching until the last occurrence of `:` and then capture in group 1 matching 16 characters other than `:`

```
^.*:([^:]{16})
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*:` Match the last occurrence of `:`
- `([^:]{16})` Capture **group 1**, match 16 chars other than `:` using the negated character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xpL2DY/1)